# symfony render a template/partial in a form

Tags: symfony-1.4, php-5.3

I am trying to render a template in a form using the `_toString()` method.
The problem I am facing is that the form does not inherit from controller and I can not do 
     $str.= $this->renderPartial('template',array('form' => $this));
How can this be achieved ?

I am using symfony 1.4 with PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a widget for it:

```
class fdWidgetFromPartial extends sfWidgetForm
{
  public function __construct($options = array(), $attributes = array())
  {
    parent::__construct($options, $attributes);

    sfProjectConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers('Partial');
  }

  protected function configure($options = array(), $attributes = array())
  {
    $this->addRequiredOption('template');
    $this->addOption('variables', array());
  }

  public function render($name, $value = null, $attributes = array(), $errors = array())
  {
    return get_partial($this->getOption('template'), array_merge(array(
      'name' => $name,
      'value' => $value,
      'attributes' => $attributes,
      'errors' => $errors,
    ), $this->getOption('variables')));
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$this->setWidget('field', new WidgetFromPartial(array(
  'template' => 'modeule/template',
  'variables' => array(
    'some_data' => $this->getObject()->getData(),
  )
)));
```

You should **NOT** use any input field in the partial.

Comment: what do you mean by not using any input field in the partial ?

Comment: Just an advice. Do not put any form element (input, select,...) into the partial as it will be sent back to the server and requires validation. If you would like to use input fields you should create a separate widget and a validator for it.

Comment: i add the form to the partial and i only render form fields , is it ok ?

Comment: I think it's not. This widget ment to be used for read only data (e.g. display a table of products in the form)... My advice if you want to embed a form or a field with multiple input elements you should create an embedded form and use a custom form formatter or create a widget. [embedded form](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms), [widget](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/05-Custom-Widgets-and-Validators)

Answer (score 0):

ok  using this [Render a partial from a task in Symfony 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576085/render-a-partial-from-a-task-in-symfony-1-4) and the 1.4 doc http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/PartialHelper

I did

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial');
```

in __toString()

and

```
get_partial('template',array('form' => $this));
```

instead of

```
$this->renderPartial('template',array('form' => $this));
```